# Preserve input value on page reload / refresh

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im trying to keep whatever a user has written into an input field inside, the input field even after the input window closes and someone reopens it. 
For example:
I type in "hello" into an empty input field, I then close the window. When I reopen the window I want to see "hello" in the field again.

Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The only way would be to store the info outside of the website, e.g. `localStorage` or server-side.

Comment: Are you referring to one window (template) in an application that you want the user to return to *while in the same application*? Or do need to retain the data after the user *exits* the application and restarts. If the later, then use the `localStorage` suggestions. If the former, use a service instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[*Window.localStorage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** to store a stringified JSON like

```
{
    "name" : "John",
    "surname" : "Doe",
    "message" : "Hello, World!"
}
```

where `name`, `surname` and `message` are the actual element `name="***"` attribute.

**[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/kL3ye6wq/1/)** (enter some values and refresh page)

```
// Get Object literal from LocalStorage
let memory = JSON.parse(localStorage.memory || "{}");

// Loop input elements on page
[...document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea')].forEach( el => {

    // prepopulate from memory
    if ( el.name in memory ) {
        el.value = memory[el.name]
    }

    // save to memory
    el.addEventListener("input", () => {
        memory[el.name] = el.value;
        localStorage.memory = JSON.stringify(memory);
    });
});
```